# How to fold paragraphs in asciidoc easily?

Tags: html, asciidoc

I use asciidoc to generate html files and know little about html.

Can I make a paragraph fold into one line and expand only when user click on it?

If JS is needed, how to insert script into asciidoc elegantly? I mean, I don't want to edit the html file generate by asciidoc.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any Javascript.

Use it.

```
.some heading
[%collapsible]
====
some content
====
```

This code will give the following result.

[image: result]

See details [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34326324/how-to-dynamically-hide-asciidoc-element).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this would be a Javascript thing you'd need to do. You'll want to use a [docinfo file](http://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#docinfo-file). Basically it's a file named `<doc-name>-docinfo.html`. Anything in that file will be placed in the `<head>` tag of the resulting html.